# Окончание sh скрипта, ошибка fi" unexpected (expecting "then")

Tags: bash, cron, sh

Изначально код был такой. Все работало.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILEPATH=/home/a/amigoalex/check.log
find /home/a/amigoalex/ -iname '*php' -cmin -120 -not -path '*/cache/*' -not -path '*/cron.php' > $FILEPATH
if [ -s $FILEPATH ]
then
mail -s 'Timeweb Amigoalex - files has been changed' mymail@yandex.ru < $FILEPATH
fi
```

Потом он перестал работать, в логах мне пишется:
*/home/a/amigoalex/check.sh: 7: /home/a/amigoalex/check.sh: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "then")*

Ну я заменил fi на then, но файл все равно не хочет работать, а в логах теперь пишет просто:
*/home/a/amigoalex/check.sh: 7: /home/a/amigoalex/check.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected*

Я погуглил, нашел вариант, что это может быть из-за лишнего символа /r

Я просто переписал код руками с нуля, в новый файл, и мне все равно выдает ошибку.

Также советуют выполнить $ dos2unix /home/pi/sh/test.sh, но я не могу этого сделать, такой команды нет, у меня просто хостинг.

Comment: так установите этот пакет/программу `dos2unix` он так и называется, ну или если всё так плохо то попробуйте конвертировать файл онлайн, гуглите `dos2unix online`

Comment: ¿А что мешает просто поменять переносы строк с `\r\n` на `\n` в текстовом редакторе?

Answer (score 0):

Эта команда помогла:

```bash
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\r$//' check.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления символа возврата каретки `\r` можно воспользоваться программой `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' /home/pi/sh/test.sh
```

Синтаксис: 's/что меняем/на что меняем/модификатор'
Ключ `-i` это пересоздать файл с изменениями, без него содержимое файла с изменениями будет распечатано в `stdout`